# Gearman is not writing anything to DB

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, amazon-rds, gearman

I'm new with gearman and cannot figure out why it's not sending anything in DB

So,

I've created new EC2 and RDS instances for gearman. RDS Engine version - MySQL 5.7.19

On EC2 I've performed:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm && yum install gearmand -y
```

Then, I've created config file:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/gearmand
```

Which contains:

```
### Settings for gearmand
OPTIONS="--port=4730 --queue-type=MySQL --mysql-host=path_to_amazon_RDS_instance --mysql-port=3306 --mysql-user=root --mysql-password='dbpass' --mysql-db=db_prod --mysql-table=queue_dev --verbose DEBUG --log-file=/var/log/gearmand.log"
```

After I started gearmand service and connected to MySQL database on RDS, I see
that gearman created mysql table queue_dev. So, I assume, that there is no error in connection and/or access.

From log file I cannot see any ERROR type messages.

Anyone can help me or hint, what additionally must be done, so gearman can send messages to DB, or how can I send any test message to db?

Answer (score 0):

`gearmand` does not persist non-background jobs at all.

Only request of the type will be persisted.

- SUBMIT_JOB_BG
- SUBMIT_JOB_HIGH_BG
- SUBMIT_JOB_LOW_BG

See [Persistent Queues](http://gearman.org/manual/job_server/#persistent_queues)

> Persistent queues were added to allow background jobs to be stored in an external durable queue so they may live between server restarts and crashes.

Comment: According to this manual:

"A persistent queue module is enabled by passing the -q or –queue-type option to gearmand."

But in my config file I already passed --queue-type=MySQL options and all other options, needed to connect to db ( host, port, user, db, table).

Comment: It looks to me your expectations are not correct. `gearmand` does not store requests of type SUBMIT_JOB in to DB.